# How to fix "AVX support is required in order to run Wasmer VM Singlepass backend"?

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm trying to run a [sample](https://github.com/near-examples/NFT) NFT contract on the Macbook with M1 chip and encounter the following failure: panicked at 'AVX support is required in order to run Wasmer VM Singlepass backend.' Saw a similar issue discussed in the [thread](https://github.com/near/nearcore/issues/3803). Any tips on this regard?

Answer (score 2):

yes, you found it, currently we do not support compiling contracts on M1 chips.

for sure this is coming but not available yet